# Why my model URDF doesn't appear in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a beginner in ROS.

I have a problem - I can't spawn my robot model into Gazebo.  As in the title.  When I use "roslaunch tortoise.launch' the Gazebo opens but it's just empty world, without robot. There is no errors or sth like that.

(I am reading a book about ROS, and all the code is just Ctrl-C Ctrl-V from it. So it's not my own code.)
This is my launch file. Named tortoise.launch in package tortoise:

```
 <launch>
<!-- Load the TortoiseBot URDF model into the parameter server -->
<param name="robot_description" textfile="tortoisebot.urdf" />

<!-- Start Gazebo with an empty world -->
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/>
<!-- UPDATED:  output="screen" in spawn_model-->

  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"  output="screen" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model tortoisebot" />  
</launch>
```

and my urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="tortoisebot">


    <link name="base_link">
     <collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="1.0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.015" iyy="0.0375" izz="0.0375" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </collision>
        
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver">
                <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
       
    </link>
    
    <link name="front_caster">
       <collision>
        <inertial>
                <mass value="0.1"/>
                <inertia ixx="0.00083" iyy="0.00083" izz="0.000167" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </collision>

        <visual>
            <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver"/>
        </visual>       
    </link>


    <joint name="front_caster_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="front_caster"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.3 0 0"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="front_wheel">
        <collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </collision>

        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
    </link>



    <joint name="front_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="front_caster"/>
        <child link="front_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.05 0 -.15"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="right_wheel">
        <collision>
        <inertial> 
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </collision>

        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>


    <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 -0.125 -.15"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="left_wheel">
        <collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        </collision>
        
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 0.125 -.15"/>
    </joint> 
</robot>
```

Please help me, I trying deal with it from 2 weeks. Thanks.

----- updated, but still with problem ----

Sorry, but the texts below didn't wanted be represended as normal code.  Better version on pastebin: [link text](https://pastebin.com/ej9ZHrQe)

The Outputs from launch:

```
   ' logging to /home/dorota/.ros/log/253db8b8-2d56-11e8-abef-84a6c8a158a1/roslaunch-dorota-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-4-PC-10539.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://dorota-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-4-PC:32931/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.12
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [10562]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [10567]
process[spawn_urdf-3]: started with pid [10572]
[ INFO] [1521671861.405168668]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1521671861.407923913]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1521671862.160813, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter
[INFO] [1521671862.167279, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1521671862.170183, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1521671862.236927158, 0.023000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Error:   Could not parse collision element for Link [base_link]
         at line 474 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
Error:   Could not parse collision element for Link [front_caster]
         at line 474 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
Error:   Could not parse collision element for Link [front_wheel]
         at line 474 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
Error:   Could not parse collision element for Link [right_wheel]
         at line 474 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
Error:   Could not parse collision element for Link [left_wheel]
         at line 474 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
[INFO] [1521671862.376278, 0.081000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1521671862.404992040, 0.104000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[spawn_urdf-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/dorota/.ros/log/253db8b8-2d56-11e8-abef-84a6c8a158a1/spawn_urdf-3*.log
```

And I have Gazebo 7.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286022/why-my-model-urdf-doesn%27t-appear-in-gazebo?/) by [dorothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/34239/dorothea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-20**:
Please add `output="screen"` to the spawn node in your launch file, and then copy and paste the output from the launch file here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-20**:
I'm going to hazard a guess and say that this is because of the missing `dynamics` elements.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-21**:
@gvdhoorn The `dynamics` tag isn't required in Gazebo 7 (but I don't know for the older versions).

Try adding this node in the launchfile :

```
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher"/>
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-21**:
Do you have a reference for that @Delb? If I understand you correctly you're saying that `dynamics` elements aren't needed any more?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-21**:
In the [joint element description](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint) it's described as optional so it could give errors in Gazebo but not prevent the model from spawning.
Also I use urdf files whithout those elements and I don't have simulation issues.

**Comment by [dorothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/34239/dorothea/) on 2018-03-21**:
@delb
Adding the node didn't change anything. Still it's only the empty World in gazebo.

@David Lu
I added this code to spawn_model, but it's still the same. I will paste the outputs to my main question.
I understand the output text as the text which appears after `roslaunch tortoisebot.launch`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-22**:
First you have an issue with your `collision` tags you can't put `inertial` tag in it, check [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML) to see which elements are required for each tag.

Secondly, I would recommend you before spawning your robot in gazebo to check in rviz if it's well constructed.

**Comment by [dorothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/34239/dorothea/) on 2018-04-05**:
Thanks a lot @Delb. My mistake was to put inertial into collision.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-05**:
@dorothea instead of putting your answer as an edit of your question, can you please put it as an answer? This way others will know that the problem is solved and can easily find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is to edit the urdf file.

There is an issue with your collision tags can't be put inertial tag in it (check here to see which elements are required for each tag).
I had to copy all the `inertial` tags and paste into the link tags and the `collision` tags I had to fill by copy the code from `visual` tag.

---

**Edit:**

I made a mistake: I put `<inertial />` into `<collision />`.
I paste the finally vesion of  my urdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="tortoisebot">


    <link name="base_link">
     <collision>
        <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver">
                <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1"/>
            </material>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
            <mass value="1.0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.015" iyy="0.0375" izz="0.0375" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>    
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.6 0.3 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver">
                <color rgba="0.75 0.75 0.75 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
       
    </link>
    
    <link name="front_caster">
       <collision>
            <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver"/>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
                <mass value="0.1"/>
                <inertia ixx="0.00083" iyy="0.00083" izz="0.000167" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                    <box size="0.1 0.1 0.3"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="silver"/>
        </visual>       
    </link>


    <joint name="front_caster_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="front_caster"/>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.3 0 0"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="front_wheel">
        <collision>
       <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </collision>
         <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
    </link>



    <joint name="front_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="front_caster"/>
        <child link="front_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="0.05 0 -.15"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="right_wheel">
        <collision>
             <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </collision>
         <inertial> 
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>


    <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 -0.125 -.15"/>
    </joint>


    <link name="left_wheel">
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/>
            <inertia ixx="5.1458e-5" iyy="5.1458e-5" izz="6.125e-5" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyz="0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.035"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
    </link>

    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_wheel"/>
        <origin rpy="-1.5708 0 0" xyz="-0.2825 0.125 -.15"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [dorothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/34239/dorothea/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0